# SQL Select - SUM the value from the row on which Grouping is being done and from the previous row

Tags: sql, select, group-by, count, db2

I have table with this data.

```
ID  IMPACT  TICKETID     OWNER    OWNERGROUP
1   1       TICKET1001            GROUP1
2   2       TICKET1001   USER1
3   3       TICKET1001   USER1
4   4       TICKET1001            GROUP1
5   5       TICKET1001   USER2   
6   6       TICKET1001            GROUP1
7   7       TICKET1001   USER1
8   8       TICKET1002            GROUP1
9   9       TICKET1003            GROUP1
10  10      TICKET1003   USER1
```

I want to summarize based on the OWNER column IMPACT value for all Tickets and I know how to do that part.

```
SELECT OWNER, SUM (IMPACT)
FROM TABLE
WHERE OWNER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OWNER
```

So the result in that case will be:

```
USER1 22  (2+3+7+10)
USER2 5   (5)
```

BUT, I need also to get the the value from the previous row where user wasn't the owner of the ticket but after that row he took the ownership.
Ticket is always first delegated to the group (GROUP1) and then user takes the ownership.
So it means that I should count for the USER1 value from the ID 1 and 6 and 9 (because he was the next first owner after those rows) and for the USER2 value from the ID 4 (because USER2 was the first next owner of the ticket).

So the final result for my grouping should be:

```
USER1 38  (1+2+3+6+7+9+10)
USER2 9   (4+5)
```

TICKET1002 does not have OWNER value at all so it should not be counted!!!

Is this possible to have this calculation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: While posting questions, please provide commands for creating table and inserting data to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `lag()`:

```
select owner,
       (sum(impact) +
        coalesce(sum(case when prev_owner is null then prev_impact end), 0)
       ) as impact
from (select t.*,
             lag(impact) over (order by id) as prev_impact,
             lag(owner) over (order by id) as prev_owner
      from t
     ) t
where owner is not null
group by owner;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon you are pure genius!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
SELECT Owner, SUM(Impact)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  @id:=ID, IMPACT, TICKETID,
  CASE WHEN OWNER IS NULL 
          THEN (SELECT OWNER FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = @id + 1  AND OWNERGROUP IS NULL)
       ELSE
          OWNER
       END AS OWNER,
  OwnerGroup
FROM Table1 AS s
 ) AS t
WHERE OWNER IS NOT NULL
Group BY OWNER;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Owner   SUM(Impact)
USER1   38
USER2   9
```

Here is the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a614b/22

Comment: Hi Jay I am trying to execute your query in my db tool but it seems like I cannot declare this @id ??? I am using DB2 tool.. I am getting error SQL Code 104... -104   ILLEGAL SYMBOL "token". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: token-list ... Is it possible to have calculation without declarations and functions? Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: can you please assist  me additionally with this? I am not sure but this sign @ it seems I cannot use in SELECT